# echo value of 2 raised to the power of {0....5} using bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting. Now, the question is self explanatory. I want to print the values 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5 using loop in bash.

I tried ..

```
for i in {0...5}; do echo 2^$i; done
```

result:

```
2^{0...5}
```

please suggest a solution

Comment: You used one dot too much: use just `{0..5}`.

Comment: that gives 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, literally . i want their values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the correct form:

```
for i in {0..5}; do echo $((2**i)); done
```

Where `{ .. }` is the *range* operator and `$(( ))` the *arithmetical evaluation* operator.

Note that the *power* operator in Bash is written `**` and not `^`.

Comment: Technically `{0..5}` is a brace expansion expression and `$((..))` is an arithmetic expression; they are not operators.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: [Roberto Reale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933925/3691422) is much better for this purpose, as it's shorter and simpler.

`2^$i;` won't work unfortunately, as bash doesn't support that operator.

You could try adding this

```
pow()
{
    echo $(( ${1:?} ** ${2:?} ))
}
```

to your code (using it like `pow [base] [exponent]` (without the brackets of course)).

*(Bare in mind I havent't tested this, so this may not work as expected)*

[Source](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/117121-mathematical-functions-bash-shell.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code also,

```
$ for i in {0..5}; do awk -v var=$i 'BEGIN{print 2^var}'; done
1
2
4
8
16
32
```

Comment: As you use a mixure of bash and awk, you could use just awk with a `for(i=0; i<=5...`